# How Do You Replace Individual Periods/Full Stops Without Replacing Decimal Points?

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

A bit of an awkward one, this; I've been gathering data using an eye-tracker, which gives its output as .txt files (Excel is also an option but there are too many samples so notepad it is). I need to have all the samples shown as numbers. Each 'sample' is a measurement of pupil size, taken one every two milliseconds. On the not-infrequent occasions that the machine loses track of someone's eye for a second or two I suddenly have a few hundered periods instead of numbers.

E.g:

```
Sub5    91.00   3300039.00  3287753

Sub5    94.00   3300041.00  3287753

Sub5    97.00   3300043.00  3287753

Sub5    97.00   3300045.00  3287753

Sub5    97.00   3300047.00  3287753

Sub5    .   3300049.00  3287753

Sub5    .   3300051.00  3287753

Sub5    .   3300053.00  3287753

Sub5    .   3300055.00  3287753

Sub5    .   3300057.00  3287753

Sub5    .   3300059.00  3287753
```

The spaces on either side of each loose period are 'Tab' button spaces, which you can't seem to indicate in a find and replace search since the 'Tab' button just tabs over to the next item in the F+R menu. This occurs irregularly and there are thousands of rows so going through manually could take hours, but Find and Replace also converts decimal points if I use it and renderes other columns of data in my output meaningless. Is there a quick way to convert all of the isolated periods into zeros without messing up the decimals? I've using notepad++ at the moment but am happy to get more advanced software if necessary. All suggestions are appreciated as the alternative is hours of trawling through the columns!

Comment: I've taken my answer down as it's not appropriate to this case

Comment: is 0.0 a valid data point in normal data? Is it appropriate for your usage to set all "no values" to 0?

Comment: Good point; it should work fine in MatLab, which is being used to process the file after this operation makes it suitable. I'm actually forwarding it on for that though so I'll check with the guy I'm sending it to and see if it'll run. Since in this case the "0" indicates a point of data which couldn't actually be collected I don't think it should matter... thaks for the heads up, though!

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents on an old and already answered question, but I see "use regexp" answers and there's way more simple :

"Tab" spaces can be copied :)

so : select a "tab", Ctrl+H, paste it to the "find" box, add your period and paste another tab after. Replace box : paste tab, add "0.0" paste tab. -> Replace All !

Got it : you juste replace all your "`tab.tab`" by "`tab0.0tab`" which should also keep your columns alignment.

Sorry for digging up a 18 month old topic :)

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to identify, including any white space, the smallest common feature that all the "needles" have that make them different from all the other parts of the "haystack".

There is no way to properly answer you without seeing the data. "Numbers" seems like a straightforward way of saying what it is, but I am guessing that you mean "decimals/floating point" numbers etc. Is there "something" between data points (e.g. any sort of white space or delimiter)?

If there is a tab before every column, you can replace all `\t.` with `\t0.0` etc.

If there is no white space, then you could replace all `..`  (2x period) with `` (nothing). Do this as many times as it takes until you get "0 replacements".

It goes without saying that you do this on a backup copy of the data.

Comment: Answered before the clarifications...In notepad++, use the "extended search mode" option to gain access to `\t`.

Comment: Right, I'll give it a go. Sorry I took a while to become suitably coherent in the question!

Comment: The solution was to use Find+Replace with the Extended search mode to replace "\t." with "\t0\t".Omitting the second tab in the Replace box caused the column to combine with the following one, which was odd, but with the second it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use text pad you could use regular expressions:

something like `([0-9]\.\.+[0-9])`

Though now you've qualified it, it might actually be easier, if you have tabs on each side:

`(\t\.\t)`

Comment: regexp is supported in notepad++ as well (with the proper option selected in the replace dialog).

Comment: Yeah, I don't know notepad++'s syntax though :)

Comment: as far as I know, it is "standard-ish" so your answer is probably usable as-is

Comment: Yeah, I tend to err on the side of caution, and he did state he was willing to try other software.

Comment: Aye, the second worked fine. Sorry again for being slow to clarify, and thanks for the help!

Comment: DOn't worry, half the help here is getting people to think their questions through.. that way both sides learn :)